# How to handle the Firebase notification when app is in foreground

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have integrated Firebase Cloud Messaging with my application.
When I sent a notification from the Firebase console, if the app is in background or not opened I receive successfully the notification,
otherwise if the app is in foreground or opened, I did not receive it.

All suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Go through this link, this is the most simplest way to handle firebase notification by app instead of server when app is in foreground and background using postman. [Firebase Notifications in Background & Foreground in Android](https://wajahatkarim.com/2018/05/firebase-notifications-in-background--foreground-in-android/)

Answer (score 99, accepted):

When app is in foreground, notifications are not generated themselves. You need to write some additional code. When message is received `onMessageReceived()` method is called where you can generate the notification. Here is the code:

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
        Log.d("msg", "onMessageReceived: " + remoteMessage.getData().get("message"));
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        String channelId = "Default";
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new  NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle())
                .setContentText(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody()).setAutoCancel(true).setContentIntent(pendingIntent);;
        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId, "Default channel", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
            manager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
        manager.notify(0, builder.build());
    }
}
```

Comment: Any new notification will replace the previous one since you use 0 as an id

Comment: Crashed my android phone's system UI.

Comment: TIP: You should also add a check for BUILD version > O. Else the notification will not appear in the emulator. My virtual device was NEXUS 5 (Which runs in Android O). I did not realize it at the first and went crazy for a few hours.

Comment: Notification behavior changes based on whether app is open or not! Any idea?

Comment: @JayPatel in case of foreground, you have full control over notification so you can . easily create pending intent(if you want to open activity other than launcher activity on click of notification).But in case of background launcher activity opens on click of notification.

Comment: It's very puzzling to me that Firebase didn't provide a helper to turn the `RemoteMessage.Notification` object into a system notification more easily. It's literally what they do behind the scenes for background notifications, and I just wish we could reuse the code instead of repeating everything...

Answer (score 5):

`FirebaseMessagingService` never work when the app is in foreground. In this case if you want to receive the message from FCM then `WakefulBroadcastReceiver`  will work for you

```
public class FirebaseDataReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {


        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            Log.d("BroadcastReceiver::", "BroadcastReceiver");
            NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle(intent.getExtras().getString("title"))
                    .setContentText(intent.getExtras().getString("message"));
            NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            manager.notify(0, builder.build());
        }
    }
```

Link `firebase` with `GCM` in play store and write the below code in manifest

```
<receiver
    android:name=".firebase.FirebaseDataReceiver"
    android:exported="true"
    android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: C2DM? Are you sure?

Comment: Yes, to receive data and to display notifications when the app is in foreground

Comment: If I'm correct, C2DM or GCM is fully deprecated and should not use.

Comment: Yes that’s true

Comment: It seems @only android's answer is enough to retrieve and show notification when the app is in foreground.

Comment: No, It is a special case when the firebase message receiver was not fired earlier in old firebase versions that we have been solved using this solution