# Unable to view my Push Notification in Oreo when app is in foreground/opened

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, android-8.0-oreo, android-push-notification

I have firebase push notifications in my application whereas I used to receive notifications when the app is in foreground, background and killed.

I recently upgraded my device to oreo(Samsung s8 plus). I even added NotificationBuilder's channel id as this is necessary from oreo.

Issue is that., here my notification delivered fine when the app is killed ., but when my app is in the foreground .,I am unable to receive/view push notifications.

Your help is highly appreciated!

**EDIT 02-05-2018**

Earlier posting my question I have the solution as mentioned in the links which tagged as duplicate here., but couldn't figure out what went wrong.Recently got my issue fixed.I am able to figure out what my issue was.Please make sure you are not using implicit broadcasts which is the mistake I have done in my case.Make sure that you are not using implicit which is not supported when you target ur app to Oreo

Here this link might be helpful

https://medium.com/@iiro.krankka/its-time-to-kiss-goodbye-to-your-implicit-broadcastreceivers-eefafd9f4f8a

Comment: Here's a link with a question similar to yours: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38451235/how-to-handle-the-fire-base-notification-when-app-is-in-foreground

Comment: Is this working on other android versions?

Comment: yes..able to receive on versions below oreo