# Android GCM message not calling onMessageReceived when the app is in the foreground

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, sendbird

According to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive):

> If you want foregrounded apps to receive notification messages or data messages, you’ll need to write code to handle the onMessageReceived callback.

What I have:

- I have the service extending `FirebaseMessagingService` and
  overriding `onMessageReceived` as explained in the documentation
  (also in the manifest and the permissions).
- The payload of the message is in the `data` map and the
  `notification` object is null (as expected).
- The notifications when the app is in the background are working as intended.
- The messages are being sent by SendBird (a 3rd party chat solution). And everything it is fine on their end and in our other clients implementations (ios, web and backend)

The problem is when the app is in the foreground the `onMessageReceived` callback is not being called.

Am I missing something? Shouldn't be the same service handling both app states of the app for the messages received? I don't want to show a system bar notification when the app is already opened, but I do want to change some elements in the UI to indicate the user that they have new messages in the chat.

Here is the code:

The service:

```
class ChatMessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService() {

override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage)

    Timber.e("----------- MESSAGE RECEIVED -------------")

    displayNotification(remoteMessage)

    sendBroadcastToActivity(remoteMessage) // 
}
```

}

in the manifest

```
        <service
        android:name=".notifications.ChatMessagingService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

firebase & gcm version

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.0'
```

Thank you all in advance

edit, this method was required by a commenter, but it does not even reach to it so I do not think it is the problem.

```
private fun sendBroadcastToActivity(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {
    val messageData = Gson().fromJson<SendBirdPNPayload>(remoteMessage.data["sendbird"], SendBirdPNPayload::class.java)
    Intent(MESSAGE_RECEIVED_ACTION).also { intent ->
        intent.putExtra("message_id", messageData.messageId)
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent)
    }
}
```

Comment: Please look into the answer here, [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38451235/how-to-handle-the-firebase-notification-when-app-is-in-foreground](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38451235/how-to-handle-the-firebase-notification-when-app-is-in-foreground)

Comment: can you show function "sendBroadcastToActivity()"?? also check the data payload you receiving in the log.

Comment: @sadat I have been reading multiple responses, but the issue is not how to display notification in the foreground, the problem is that onMessageReceived is not being called. So it does not enter and hence does nothing.

Comment: @Nazimch done, but the flow does not reach that method anyway

Comment: check the "remoteMessage().getData()"  in your log and see is it giving something.

Comment: @Nazimch i can check it only when the app is in background, in that case it is getting the data as expected. But there is no way to check it when the app is in foreground, because it does not enter there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for trying to help. We have found that it is not an issue with our code, everything was as it is supposed to. The 3rd party solution for chat would not send a push notification if the user is connected to the chat (via sdk) and the application is in foreground. So we have to use another technique to make changes in the UI.

Again, thank you all for trying to help!

Answer (score 0):

The class name which extends FirebaseMessagingService and the name of service you define in your Manifest.xml is different. Try this:

```
<service
    android:name = ".ChatMessagingService"
    android:stopWithTask="false">
    <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Comment: @AlbertoGarrido I updated my answer please try this. Hope it works

Comment: Yeah that was me trying to hide the company name :D in the real code the name was the same, sorry. Does the package path to the serve change anything? My service is in {$app_id}.notifications.ChatMessagingService should I remove the "notifications" part in the manifest?